# is it possible to return a default value when using enum in dart

Tags: dart

Now I am define a enum in dart like this:

```
enum LoginType {
  PHONE,
  WECHAT
}

extension ResponseStatusExtension on LoginType{
  static const statusCodes = {
    LoginType.PHONE: 1,
    LoginType.WECHAT: 2,
  };


  int get statusCode => statusCodes[this];
}
```

I am upgrade to flutter 2.0.1 and support null safety and now it tell me :

```
A value of type 'int?' can't be returned from the function 'statusCode' because it has a return type of 'int'.
```

but I want to make it return a default not null value to make the code rubust and did not have to handle null when using this enum. what should I do to make it return a default value? is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your error is that the `[]` operator on `Map` is nullable since it has this behavior:

> The value for the given `key`, or ***`null` if key is not in the map***.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.2/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html

If you are sure your `Map` always contains the requested `key` you can add a `!` after the use of `[]` operator like this:

```
  int get statusCode => statusCodes[this]!;
```

This will make a null-check at runtime and fail if a `null` value is returned. But this should not be a problem if you are sure `null` is never returned from the `Map`.

### Bonus tip

If you want to be able to have a default value returned from a `Map` in case the `Map` does not contain a given `key` you can add the following extension to `Map`:

```
extension MapDefaultValue<K, V> on Map<K, V> {
  V get(K k, V defaultValue) => containsKey(k) ? this[k] as V : defaultValue;
}
```

Notice that `defaultValue` must be a compatible type for `key` in the `Map` so you cannot use `null` as `defaultValue` if `null` are not allowed as a `value` in the `Map`.